# Free swf files hosting for wordpress blog

Tags: hosting

Picasa and Flickr provide Photo service. Is there any service for swf files so that i could share and use `swf` file in my blog? I don't like to upload `swf` on my wordpress hosting.

I believe Google, Microsoft and Yahoo services only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a generic file sharing and hosting site work? If you place the file in a public [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) folder and reference it from your site? See the Web Applications Stack Exchange for [more online file storage providers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/638/online-file-storage-services).

Make sure you check the [Cross-domain policy](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html): if the Flash file hosted on `dropbox.com` needs to access data from `yourdomain.com`, you need a `crossdomain.xml` file on `yourdomain.com` that specifies that Flash files from `dropbox.com` are allowed to access data.

Comment: Is there any service related to Google, Microsoft or yahoo? I don't want to use other we can't trust another services.

Comment: @Brij: The linked Web Applications question lists Microsoft Live Mesh (there is also the similar Live Sync and SkyDrive), and Google Docs that now allows arbitrary uploads (but only for professional accounts?). I don't know whether Yahoo has such a service. You could also try to put it in a "cloud app" from the Google App Engine or Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting it into any of the Youtube supported formats and putting it up there? Then just embed in your blog post.

Comment: SWF files can be more than just videos, so going via YouTube will probably not be a solution.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, but then he was so specific about using Google/MS/Yahoo services.